# Matlab interpolate value from lookup table

Tags: matlab, interpolation, lookup-tables

I'm writing a tool that builds a sort of lookup table (two) containing samples of measurements and then I want to give myself a measurement, check inside the lookup table the one which is the closest one and return me the extracted value. I would like to get as result the same value that I passed to the tool by hand.
Let's say that I build two matrices that are my lookup tables containing two sets of measurements, after I defined my coordinate system `X,Y` as a meshgrid

```
x = rand(101); y = rand(101);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
```

[image]

for each point `(Xi,Yi)` correspond a pair of measurements `(Ai,Bi)`

```
A = rand(101); B = rand(101);
```

In this way I get something that maps my measurements like this, for both A and B

[image]

Now what I would like is give a direction where re-compute the measurements by hand, said `x = rand(1)` and `y = rand(1)` to which will correspond the pair `a,b` which are not necessary equal to a point of the map like this,

[image]

comparare these values with the ones inside `A,B` and print it. In theory if the pair `a,b` corresponds exactly with the particular element of `A,B` it means that I can extract the correspondent point of the map.

I do something similar in this way

```
row = (size(A,1)+1)/2;
col = (size(B,2)+1)/2;

[~,m] = min(abs(A(row,:)-a));
[~,n] = min(abs(B(:,col)-b));

x_estimated = X(n,m);
y_estimated = Y(n,m);
```

trying to extract the point of my map closest to the set of values that I put by hand, resulting
[image]

As you see, there is a sampling error between the actual point and the extracted point from this code. What I need is that the extimated point (light green) is equal to the point computed "by hand" (in pink).

Therefore I think I need a sort of weighted extraction, not something that checks the closest set of values.

Does exist something similar in Matlab (an interpolation basically) that do that automatically? If not, can you suggest me an easy way to extract these values?

**EDIT**:
as suggested, I tried with `interp2` like this

```
x_estimation = interp2(A,B,X,a,b);
y_estimation = interp2(A,B,Y,a,b);
```

but gives me compilation error for "not a valid MESHGRID", therefore I tried with `scatteredInterpolant` like this

```
F_x = scatteredInterpolant(X(:),Y(:),A);
x_estimation = F_x(a,b);
```

but gives me a completely wrong value

**EDIT2**
So, I try to make myself clearer  with my problem.
I define `X` and `Y` as my coordinate system building a grid where everything that I compute is inside this grid.

Then I perform first a complete measurement computing in some way `A` and `B` that give me the measurement in one of the two direction. Therefore I need both of them to have the information in the two directions.

So far, I have inside these two matrices, sampled measurements. Then I give by hand a fixed position where perform the measurement (which is still inside my grid but in an arbitrary position), recompute the measurements obtaining two scalar `a` and `b` and extract from the matrices `A` and `B` the closest element to the pair `a-b`. The result it is supposed to be the same as the one that I gave by hand at the begin of the routine, with a very small error (as small as possible, hoping 0)

Comment: Search for bilinear interpolation in the docs. If it requires a special toolbox, just apply linear interpolation to the edges of the box containing a,b

Comment: From your question it's not clear if you want closest-neighbour interpolation or somehing smoother like linear interpolation. In any case, see [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)

Comment: The point is that `a` and `b` in my code are not exactly the ones that I add by hand, but are results of computations. In the case of the extraction that I perform in my code (with the closest points and so on...) I obtain the correct result, with some error due to the sampling distance, while with `interp2` I get `NaN` because thinks that is out of scale

Comment: Are `a` and `b` sure to be in the range covered by `A` and `B` respectively?

Comment: Yes they are. Let's say I use `interp2`, I will use `x_estimation = interp2(X,Y,A,a,b)` and `y_estimation = interp2(X,Y,B,a,b)` I believe the out of range is for X,Y but if I exchange X,Y with A,B in the code, I get some compilation errors, since `(X,Y)` is my grid in the coordinate system, wile A,B are the two lookup tables and the values that I give as `(a,b)` smaller or equal than the maximum value inside A or B

Comment: Wait, this is confusing. You have `X` and `Y` as grid positions. The you have `A`, and `B` as measurements at those grid positions. Then you have `a` and `b` as new measurements, and you want to estimate the location of those measurements? Is that right? This is not what is typically called a look-up table, it’s the other way around. You need to clarify this in your question, because everybody here understood you differently. Are `A` and `B` related somehow to `X` and `Y`? Are they at least monotonous functions?

Comment: Oh, but you want `(x_estimated,y_estimated) = (a,b)`. Now I’m thoroughly confused.

Comment: I added few lines and hoping modified the images to me clearer. I hope this will not add other confusion.